# Giving unique id to EditText inside a custom view for every different instance of the custom view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-custom-view, screen-orientation

I have a custom view ProfileInputView

profile_input_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>

  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="28dp"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/label_text"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
      android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
      android:textAllCaps="true"
      android:textColor="@color/oppiaPrimaryText"
      android:textSize="12sp" />

    <EditText
      android:id="@+id/input"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
      android:background="@drawable/add_profile_edit_text_background"
      android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
      android:padding="8dp"
      android:textColor="@color/oppiaPrimaryText"
      android:textSize="14sp"
      android:textStyle="italic" />

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/error_text"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:textColor="@color/red" />
  </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

I have created two ProfileInputView instances inside this layout

admin_pin_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:profile="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
  <data>
    <variable
      name="viewModel"
      type="org.oppia.app.profile.AdminPinViewModel" />
  </data>
  <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollViewAdminPin"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/addProfileBackground">
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
      android:id="@+id/admin_auth_container"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="@color/addProfileBackground">
      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/admin_pin_main_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/admin_pin_requirement_description"
        android:textColor="@color/oppiaPrimaryText"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:paddingStart="32dp"
        android:paddingEnd="32dp"/>
      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/admin_pin_warning_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/admin_pin_pin_description"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="@color/oppiaPrimaryText"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/admin_pin_main_text"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:paddingStart="32dp"
        android:paddingEnd="32dp"/>
      <org.oppia.app.profile.ProfileInputView
        android:id="@+id/input_pin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/admin_pin_warning_text"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:label="@string/admin_pin_new_pin"
        app:isPasswordInput="true"
        app:inputLength="5"
        profile:error="@{viewModel.pinErrorMsg}"/>
      <org.oppia.app.profile.ProfileInputView
        android:id="@+id/input_confirm_pin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/input_pin"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:label="@string/admin_pin_new_confirm"
        app:isPasswordInput="true"
        app:inputLength="5"
        profile:error="@{viewModel.confirmPinErrorMsg}"/>
      <Button
        android:id="@+id/submit_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/admin_pin_submit"
        style="@style/StateButtonActive"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/input_confirm_pin"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"/>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
  </ScrollView>
</layout>
```

How do I give unique ids to each ProfileInputView's EditText fields.

Basically, when I switch the orientation of the screen each instance has the same value of text since they have the same ids for their EditTexts. So I want to give unique ids for each instances' EditText.

Answer (score 0):

you can create an extra attr

```xml
 <declare-styleable name="ProfileInputView">
        <attr name="extra_id_input1" format="int" />
        <attr name="extra_id_input2" format="int" />
        <attr name="extra_id_input3" format="int" />
 </declare-styleable>
```

call this from your custom ProfileInputView, something like this:

```xml
<org.oppia.app.profile.ProfileInputView
        android:id="@+id/input_confirm_pin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/input_pin"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:label="@string/admin_pin_new_confirm"
        app:isPasswordInput="true"
        app:inputLength="5"
        app:extra_id_input1 = "1"
        app:extra_id_input1 = "2"
        app:extra_id_input1 = "3"
        profile:error="@{viewModel.confirmPinErrorMsg}"/>
```

and in your component side do something like this:

```
 init {
      // ...

   label_text.id = attributeArray.getInt(R.styleable.ProfileInputView_extra_id_input1,0)
input.id = attributeArray.getInt(R.styleable.ProfileInputView_extra_id_input2,0)
error_text.id = attributeArray.getInt(R.styleable.ProfileInputView_extra_id_input3,0)

// ...
}
```

The proper way to implement this could be has a custom component for EditText and **TextView** to avoid many extra **ids**, so at the end could do something like this:

```kotlin
init {
//...

label_text.id = this.id
input.id = this.id

//..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()` to do manual saving and restoring of the view's text.

```
class ProfileInputView ... {

    private val input: EditText

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(): Parcelable? {
        // create saved state object... see tutorials on this

        savedState.inputText = input.text
        return savedState
    }

    override fun onRestoreInstanceState(savedState: Parcelable) {
        // call through to super

        input.text = savedState.inputText
    }
```

Comment: An example tutorial on implementing `onSaveInstanceState()` for custom views: https://medium.com/super-declarative/android-how-to-save-state-in-a-custom-view-30e5792c584b